# Android - Difference between View.getResources() and View.getContext().getResources()

Tags: android, android-view

I wanted to understand the real difference in using `View.getResources()` and `View.getContext().getResources()`.

For example, I have to set a color to a `TextView` from resource..

```
view.setTextColor(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue));
```

or

```
view.setTextColor(view.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue));
```

Both works , but as per the documents...

`View.getResources()` - Returns the resources associated with this view.

`View.getContext()` - Returns the context the view is running in, through which it can access the current theme, resources, etc.

Your thoughts are welcome....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nothing. As seen in the source code:

```
private final Resources mResources;

public View(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mResources = context != null ? context.getResources() : null;
    ...
}

public Resources getResources() {
    return mResources;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would guess the `View.getResources()` is a shortcut for `getContext().getResources()`.

You could search the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/) if you really want to know.

Answer (score 0):

`getContext().getResources()` returns resources of the contest in which `View` is running i.e. this can be used when views are implemented dynamically while `View.getResource()`. Return a Resources instance for your application's package.